# Reproducing kernel Hilbert sapce

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces

I encountered the following claim (verbatim):

**Theorem** Let $V$ be a subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\{e_n\}$ be a orthonormal basis of $V$. The $V$ is a reproducing kernel Hilbert space with kernel

$$
K(x,y) = \sum_n e_n(x)e_n(y).
$$

For any function $f \in V$,

$$
f(y) = \int f(x) K(x,y) dy.
$$

*Questions*:

- I am under the impression that a RKHS is a Hilbert space of functions, where pointwise evaluation is a bounded functional. $L^2$ is not even a space of functions, how does the claim make sense (e.g. take an ONB for the entire $L^2$)?
- Also, are there no convergence requirements on the reproducing kernel $K$, or is it purely formal?

Comment: A formula like that would hold if $V$ were a reproducing kernel Hilbert space (so in particular it would have to be a space of functions).  As written it does not make sense. Where did you encounter this?

Comment: p29 of Statistical Modeling by Wavelets, by Vidakovic.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked it out on a Google Books preview.  Whatever it is they're doing there, it is nonstandard from my experience.  In an actual RKHS, the sum would be convergent, and the identity would be a consequence of Parseval's identity.  I don't really know what to say in an answer though, because I don't know the context of what type of object the author *does* have in mind.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. Struck me as a bit strange, hence the question.